# How to split such way

Tags: javascript, split

I tried to get specific value from a `textarea` . I know this can be done by JavaScript's `split` method. I can't understand how to do.

```
  <textarea
    name="css_sheet" rows="5">
    Hey @shaikatssj. How are you?
    </textarea>
```

Or

```
 <textarea name="css_sheet" rows="5">
        @name
      </textarea>
```

I want to get value **shaikatssj** or **name**

How to do it?

Comment: What, *exactly*, marks the text you want from the rest of the text? It looks like you want it to start at the character after the "@", but how do you tell where the end is? Would "@Some.Name" count as the value you want?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but this will get the text from your element and strip everything out except the name. Based on the example username you provided.

```
var name = document.getElementsByName('css_sheet')[0].value;
name = name.split("@")[1];
name = name.split(" ")[0];
name = name.split(".")[0];
```

This code will retrieve the text from the element, then retrieve the word in that text starting with `@`, and also remove the `.` at the end of it.

Comment: Thanks.. Let me try. Then i will feedback

Comment: This only works for the given example. When i try with this example it doesn't work <textarea
name="css_sheet" rows="5">Once upon a time there was a king named @shaikatssj.who was brave.</textarea>

Comment: Will there always be an @ at the start of the username and a . at the end?

Comment: No only a @ name @ anything @ anytext

Comment: Ok updated my answer. This code will get the text from the element and then give you the usernamr that starts with `@`. Also removes the `.` at the end, but if you want that left in, just remove the last line of the code

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go with something like this

```
function findThatThing(string)
{
    return string
              .match(/@([^\s,;!.]+)/g)                         //Match each @ until next white space or some punctuation
              .map(function(v){return v.substring(1); });  //Remove the @ from each result
}
```

for example

```
findThatThing("Hello @john and @jane, you can tag by using a @ sign!")
```

will return

```
["john", "jane"]
```

You can further shrink the code if *ES6* is allowed.